# Providing a request timeout while pushing a message to SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS in my project. I want to provide a timeout while pushing a message to SQS standard queue. By timeout (not the visibility timeout) I mean that, if my message is not pushed to SQS in say 200 ms, then I will retry to push it after sometime. I am using JAVA APIs for the same.

Initially I tried to handle the timeout myself by asking a Callable task to push the message to SQS, it returned me a future object and I waited using it by providing a timeout. But this resulted in the request being sent to SQS, while the message is being pushed, my timeout comes into picture and before receiving the response of this already pushed message, my code thinks it is a timeout because of this future object.

When I go to the documentation of SQS, I don't find anything related to providing a request timeout while calling SQS push, pull or delete.

```
final Future<ISendMessageResult> future = timeoutHelperThreadPool.getExecutor().submit(() -> {
  return getQueueStore().sendMessage(request).get();
});
try {
  sendMessageResult = future.get(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  logger.info("SQS_PUSH_SUCCESSFUL");
  return true;

} catch (final TimeoutException e) {
  logger.error("SQS_PUSH_TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION");
}
```

Is there anyway I can ensure that if I have received a timeout, my message is not pushed to SQS or vice-versa ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you are either solving the wrong problem, or trying to solve an essentially impossible problem, perhaps due to lack of familiarity with the complexity of the underlying actions that are occurring when you push a message to SQS.

All of these actions require a non-zero amount of time, and all of them are variable, to some extent...

---

The SQS request is transformed into an HTTP request.

The request is signed.

*Proceeding past this point, you are effectively committed to sending the message if no failure occurs.*

*The next three steps may or may not need to happen, for each message.  It depends on whether you have already recently interacted with the service, which might mean you have a cached DNS response, or even a reusable TCP connection with TLS established, in HTTP keep-alive waiting for the next request, but this is a wildcard.*

A DNS query looks up the SQS endpoint.

A TCP connection is established to the endpoint.

A TLS (SSL) session is established.

The HTTP request is sent over the wire.

*At this point, you are still waiting and the clock is still ticking, but there is now nothing you can do to stop the request from being processed, and there is still a lot of work to do.  Closing the connection* might *cause the service to stop processing the request, but there is no reason to expect that it will, because the service is unlikely to see that the connection is closed until it tries to write the response... at which point, it's irrelevant.*

The HTTP request is received on the wire. (This item is listed separately from the previous item because transmission of the request on the wire also requires a non-zero amount of time.)

The service checks whether the request is expired.

The service checks whether the request is correctly signed.

The service checks whether the signing user is authorized to perform the requested action.

The service actually processes the requested action.

The service generates a response.

The response is sent on the wire.

The response is received on the wire.

The response is parsed by the client.

---

As is true with essentially any web service, things are out of your control once the request arrives at the destination.

**tl;dr: in the face of a timeout, it is not possible to achieve any level of assurance that the message was not sent.**

See also [the Two Generals' Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).

However, this is one of the problems solved by SQS FIFO queues.  FIFO queues support the assignment of a message deduplication ID -- by you -- to each message, which allows you to *safely* retry delivering a message to SQS for a maximum period of 5 minutes.  During this time window, if you do send the same message to the same queue (due, perhaps, to the ambiguity introduced by a timeout), the duplicate message is discarded by the service but the response tells you the delivery succeded, because it did... earlier.

> The message deduplication ID is the token used for deduplication of sent messages. If a message with a particular message deduplication ID is sent successfully, any messages sent with the same message deduplication ID are accepted successfully but aren't delivered during the 5-minute deduplication interval.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html

Answer (score 1):

Inside you catch block you can try

```
catch (final TimeoutException e) {
  future.cancel(true);
  logger.error("SQS_PUSH_TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION");
}
```

One point to be noted here is if message is already posted to SQS by the time the thread gets interrupted you'll get false negative. I suggest you set some generous value for timeout

Comment: Yes exactly, providing a suitable timeout can avoid this problem, however there may be cases where if timeout varies because of network or something, then we can come across this issue. But as you told I will probably calculate a suitable timeout for this one. Thanks